# How to stop a specific Thread among others?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm using threads for a project which look like this :

thread1 = Thread(target=function, args=('x','y',1,2))

thread2 = Thread(target=function, args=('a','b',1,2))

thread1.start()

thread2.start()

Everything is working but I wanted to add an option to my code. To kill my threads i'm currently using While X==True in my targeted function. So when I want to kill a Thread i have to pass While==False.
The issue is doing that kill all the threads who use this function.

So how can i kill only thread1 without doing the same for thread2 if both were running together and using the same targeted function ?

Thank you !

Below a simplified example of what i'm actually doing

`def test_thread(freq):
    starttime=time.time()
    while RUN==True:
        try:
            if 1==1:
                print('1')
                sleep(freq - ((time.time() - starttime) % freq))
        except Exception as Ex:
            print(Ex)
            pass`

```
RUN = True
run_test = Thread(target=test_thread, args=(20))
run_test.start()
```

Comment: You could pass a different, mutable object as an argument to each of the two threads. Have the thread function loop until the given object's state has been changed. Change the state of one object, but not the other in the main thread.

Comment: Hello Solomon thanks for your answer. Yes I can do that but i will have to make a function for each thread no ? A first function with While Run_Thread1==True and a second with While Run_Thread2==True as its not a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a different, mutable object as an argument to each of the two threads:

```
class Stopper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
    def ok_to_keep_going(self):
        return self.flag
    def stop_now(self):
        self.flag = False

def test_thread(freq, stopper):
    ...
    while stopper.ok_to_keep_going():
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1_stopper = Stopper()
    t2_stopper = Stopper()
    t1 = Thread(target=test_thread, args=(T1_FREQ, t1_stopper))
    t2 = Thread(target=test_thread, args=(T2_FREQ, t2_stopper))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Now you can stop thread 1 by calling `t1_stopper.stop_now()`, or stop thread 2 by calling `t2_stopper.stop_now()`

---

Or, for fewer lines of code:

```
def test_thread(freq, stopper):
    ...
    while stopper[0]:
        ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1_stopper = [True]
    t2_stopper = [True]
    t1 = Thread(target=test_thread, args=(T1_FREQ, t1_stopper))
    t2 = Thread(target=test_thread, args=(T2_FREQ, t2_stopper))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Now you stop thread `t1` by setting `t1_stopper[0]=False`.

Comment: Thank you so much i will try that its exactly what i wanted. I'm still learning so this help a lot, definitely have to learn more about Class and the theta that I did not know about.